What kind of A/C disconnect switch is this?
I recently bought a house and the A/C system is missing the cutoff switches. I was able to replace one successfully already but I'm stuck on this one - it’s missing the door cover with the model info sticker. It's for sure not a Midwest Electric P065P or a P035F - I bought both and neither works.
Does anybody know what this archaic A/C disconnect switch is?


Not sure I get the question.   A whole new disconnect box is about $20.   Why do you need to identify the old one?    You're not trying to buy the missing parts are you?

I am trying to buy the missing part, even if I have to buy the whole box. It's not so much about the money for the part/box it's more about avoiding the time/money sinkhole of permitting in my city. Putting a new key in doesn't need a permit, but replacing the box probably does.

https://www.midwestelectric.com/contact-us

This is one of those situations where I'd let common sense prevail and just put in a modern disconnect. Replacing a simple device with a comparable modern part shouldn't call for a permit.

Usually a straight replacement does not need a permit.  Do you need a permit to replace an outlet/light/switch?  Adding a new circuit usually does need a permit.  This is for single family owned detached homes, rentals/multi-family homes need an electrician.
